# Heroku, mLab and Node.js: Application Error - Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

I am new to Node.js and Heroku and am trying to host my first application on Heroku but am having issues with the deployment. I have been following this tutorial to deploy the app: https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-mongodb-with-a-node-application-on-heroku

In cmd prompt I have done the following:
1. heroku
2. heroku login
3. heroku create app
4. git push heroku master
5. heroku ps:scale web=1
6. heroku open
7. heroku logs --tail  (below is a list of the log messages I see after heroku open)

On my mLab console I have created a database, collection and user and defined my mongo URI as the following:

```
'mongodb://admin:********@asdf1234.mlab.com:13122/app'
```

If I start my Node app locally, I can successfully create data into this database, but when I try to access my app from Heroku, I get the application error webpage. I know I must be missing a steps somewhere? I believe this is related to Mongoose?

```
2016-05-03T02:27:29.458496+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-05-03T02:27:33.077531+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-05-03T02:27:35.383818+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-05-03T02:27:35.383872+00:00 app[web.1]: > app@0.0.0 start /app
2016-05-03T02:27:35.383878+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2016-05-03T02:27:35.383887+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-05-03T02:27:35.587955+00:00 app[web.1]: { [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
2016-05-03T02:27:35.589136+00:00 app[web.1]: js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
2016-05-03T02:27:35.947930+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2016-05-03T02:27:35.947945+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2016-05-03T02:27:35.947946+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2016-05-03T02:27:35.986323+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-05-03T02:27:35.986338+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:242
2016-05-03T02:27:35.986339+00:00 app[web.1]:         process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
2016-05-03T02:27:35.986341+00:00 app[web.1]:                                       ^
2016-05-03T02:27:35.986344+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
2016-05-03T02:27:35.986345+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:893:11)
2016-05-03T02:27:35.986346+00:00 app[web.1]:     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:916:20)
2016-05-03T02:27:35.986347+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1075:14)
2016-05-03T02:27:35.997520+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-05-03T02:27:36.009323+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-79-generic
2016-05-03T02:27:36.009834+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-05-03T02:27:36.010139+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.11.0
2016-05-03T02:27:36.010913+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
2016-05-03T02:27:36.011252+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-05-03T02:27:36.011483+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! app@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
2016-05-03T02:27:36.011697+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-05-03T02:27:36.011937+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2016-05-03T02:27:36.012344+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the app@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
2016-05-03T02:27:36.012587+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2016-05-03T02:27:36.012830+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the app package,
2016-05-03T02:27:36.013080+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-05-03T02:27:36.013296+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-05-03T02:27:36.013522+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
2016-05-03T02:27:36.013730+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-05-03T02:27:36.013943+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs app
2016-05-03T02:27:36.014152+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-05-03T02:27:36.014360+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls app
2016-05-03T02:27:36.014579+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-05-03T02:27:36.021124+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-05-03T02:27:36.021429+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-05-03T02:27:36.021644+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-05-03T02:27:36.772785+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-03T02:27:36.779023+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

My package.json file looks like this if that helps:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "express-session": "^1.13.0",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "mongodb": "~1.4.4",
    "mongoose": "^4.4.6",
    "monk": "~1.0.1",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

### EDIT:

All I was missing was the node version in my package.json, the following fixed it for me:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "4.3.2"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The following error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Basically says it's trying to connect to MongoDB on `127.0.0.1` which would be the Heroku container not mLab, are you sure you are reading the MongoDB url from `Process.env` and trying to connect to that url?

Comment: It was actually connecting to the right server and not localhost. Turns out all I was missing was the node version. See my updated post for the answer. Thanks for the help though!